OneToOne relation and IntegrityConstraintViolation in subscriber
I have a OneToOne relation in symfony defined like this:
#[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'account')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?User $user = null;

#[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user')]
private ?Account $account = null;

I create the user without problem, but later in a subscriber i try:
$account = new Account();
$account->setUser($event->getUser());
$this->em->persist($account);
$this->em->flush();

i encounter a UniqueConstraintViolationException
i have deleted the cascade persist thinking it was that but still the same error. Any idea ?

Did you check if the User entity you are getting from your event does not have an account already?

Yes don't have, it looks like it persist 2 times
